# Is new badges will be introduced related with question in future?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today I was viewing Badge section https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges . But I found there is no `Badge` for a question who is having total of answer more than `10` OR `15` OR `any number` .

For example **If a question is having `10` then a new `Bronze` badge should be awarded to user.**

For example **If a question is having `50` then a new `Silver` badge should be awarded to user.**

For example **If a question is having `100` then a new `Gold` badge should be awarded to user.**

So my question is , is there should be a badge for these kind of questions who is having most answers?

## Edit

Now I knows that the badges for question who has answers more than 10 OR 15 from the below comments. Now I even know that this is not even practical to give badge for user because there question has more numbers of answer.

Now my question is what new kind of badges should be awarded to user related with their high quality questions?

Are all badges related with questions introduced in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges OR any new badge will be introduced in future?

Please bear with this, I am trying to improve the quality of this question. If anyone thinks that the title should be changed , they can change the title. Thanks

Comment: Having 100 answers is not worth a gold badge. It's worth being closed, because if it has *that many* answers, it's probably nowhere near constructive.

Comment: 1000 answers? Sorry, but 990 other answers are most probably not read by anyone visiting the question. People usually stop at the first or second answer, and very rarely that they look the next page of answers. (This is ignoring the fact that the question is very likely to be not constructive).

Comment: You have mistaken this site for a forum where we want lots of conversation. This is no such site. We want the single best answer. Everything else is noise.

Comment: @user414076 I knows this that we want only 2-3 best answer not so many per question. I asked this question 2 month ago. Now I am trying to lift the ban on asking question by improving the questions, so I can't change the original question see edited part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is what new kind of badges should be awarded to user related with their high quality questions?

We already have badges rewarding high quality questions - they're questions which receive a lot of attention or interest or positive feedback.

[image: Picture of the Question Badges section of the Badges page, highlighting badges for a question being favourited by many users, badges for receiving high numbers of votes, and badges for receiving high numbers of views]